# Python - Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-venv

I am having issues using venv in conjunction with the requests module. I am able to initiate a virtual environment just fine (python -m venv venv from powershell) as well as activate it (venv/Scripts/Activate/). I am also able to install the library 'requests' just fine via pip 'pip install requests'.

However when I go to run a requests get function such as :

```
requests.get(
  url = url,
  params = {}
)
```

in a py file I get the following error:

**urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.**

Any ideas on how to fix this? Using windows 10, Python 3.8.5, pip 20.1.1, requests 2.25.1, pyOpenSSL 20.0.1

Comment: do you have openssl installed?

Comment: I have pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 installed

Comment: what version is your urllib3? I can not reproduce your error with package versions, also there is an update for pip.

Comment: urllib3 version is 1.26.4. Do you think my old version of pip could be having an unwanted effect?